# No me funcionan los submenús en Laravel con el paquete nwidart/laravel-menus

Tags: php, laravel, menú

Estoy utilizando el siguiente paquete de Laravel: [nwidart/laravel-menus](https://nwidart.com/laravel-menus/v1/introduction), y no me funcionan los submenús (Nwidart\Menus\Facades\Menu).

A continuación muestro el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ App::getLocale() }}">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
      <title>{{ config('app.name', 'home') }}</title>
      <!-- Styles -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
      {{-- 
      <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
      --}}
      <style>
         body {
            padding-top: 65px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
         }
         /* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
         .body-content {
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
         }
         /* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
         will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column.
         Also, add a 8pm to the bottom margin
         */
         .dl-horizontal dt {
            white-space: normal;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
         }
         /* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
         input,
         select,
         textarea,
         .uploaded-file-group,
         .input-width-input {
            max-width: 380px;
         }
         .input-delete-container {
            width: 46px !important;
         }
         /* Vertically align the table cells inside body-panel */
         .panel-body .table > tr > td {
            vertical-align: middle;
         }
         .panel-body-with-table {
            padding: 0;
         }
         .mt-5 {
            margin-top: 5px !important;
         }
         .mb-5 {
            margin-bottom: 5px !important;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      @php
      Menu::create('navbar', function($menu) 
      {
         $menu->url ('/home', trans('home.title'));
         $menu->dropdown(trans('home.ppal_database'), function ($sub) 
         {
            $sub->url('/customers', trans('home.adm_db_customers'));
            $sub->url('/invoices', trans('home.adm_db_invoices'));
            $sub->url('/details', trans('home.adm_db_details'));
            $sub->url('/products', trans('home.adm_db_products'));
         });

         $menu->dropdown(trans('home.ppal_stadistics'), function ($sub) 
         {
            $sub->dropdown(trans('home.std_customers'), function ($sub) 
            {                    
               $sub->url('/home', trans('home.std_cust_solvency'));
               $sub->url('/home', trans('home.std_cust_products'));
            });
            $sub->divider();
            $sub->url('/home', trans('home.std_products_sales'));
         });

         $menu->dropdown(trans('home.ppal_invoice'), function ($sub) {
            $sub->header(trans('home.subtitle_3'));
            $sub->url('/home', trans('home.inv_invoice_create'));
            $sub->url('/home', trans('home.inv_invoice_fix'));
         });
         // $menu->url('/logout', trans('home.logout'));
      });
      @endphp
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar">A</span>
               <span class="icon-bar">B</span>
               <span class="icon-bar">C</span>
               </button>
               <a href="{!! url('/') !!}" class="navbar-brand">{{ config('app.name', 'home') }}</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="{!! url('/') !!}">Home Laravel</a></li>
               </ul>
               @if (Route::has('login'))
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  @if (Auth::check())
                  //  
                  <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
                  {!! Menu::render('navbar') !!}
                  @else
                  <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">{{ trans('login') }}</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">{{ trans('register') }}</a></li>
                  @endif
               </ul>
               @endif
            </div> <!--/.nav-collapse -->
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container body-content">
         @yield('content')
      </div>
      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
         integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      {{-- <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){

              // sends the uploaded file file to the fielselect event
             $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
                 var input = $(this);
                 var label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');

                 input.trigger('fileselect', [label]);
             });

             // Set the label of the uploaded file
             $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, label) {
                 $(this).closest('.uploaded-file-group').find('.uploaded-file-name').val(label);
             });

             // Deals with the upload file in edit mode
             $('.custom-delete-file:checkbox').change(function(e){
                 var self = $(this);
                 var container = self.closest('.input-width-input');
                 var display = container.find('.custom-delete-file-name');

                 if (self.is(':checked')) {
                     display.wrapInner('<del></del>');
                 } else {
                     var del = display.find('del').first();
                     if (del.is('del')) {
                         del.contents().unwrap();
                     }
                 }
             }).change();

             // Sets the validator defaults
             $.validator.setDefaults({
                 errorElement: "span",
                 errorClass: "help-block",
                 highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                     $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                 },
                 unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                     $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                 },
                 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                     if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                         error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                     } else if(element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
                         error.appendTo(element.closest(':not(input, label, .checkbox, .radio)').first());
                     } else {
                         error.insertAfter(element);
                     }
                 }
             });

             // Makes sure any input with the required class is actually required
             $('form').each(function(index, item){
                 var form = $(item);
                 form.validate();

                 form.find(':input.required').each(function(i, input){
                     $(input).attr('required', true);
                 });
             });

         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: traduce tu pregunta, aqui es la versión en español de stack over flow

Comment: Hola Gustavo! Bienvenido a Stack Overflow **en español**, por favor traduce tu pregunta o esta puede ser cerrada. También puedes terminar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio :)

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podras aclarar que quiere decir no me funciona?